# Docusign webhooks listener not receiving event notification

Tags: docusignapi

We have a soap URL which receives webhooks from docusign as per configured status. It was sending webhooks but all of sudden it stopped receiving it. I have enablelogging turned is set to true and checked in admin connect tab and nothing in logs or failure as well. We used to get logs there before. We have a demo account.

Nothing has been changed in our code. Can anyone please suggest what could have cause this issue and how to resolve it

Regards,
Dishant

following request data sent to docusign restapi

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "name": "00098O01.pdf"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Test",
  "eventNotification": {
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent",
        "includeDocuments": "false"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      }
    ],
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "recipientEvents": [
      {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      },
      {
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "recipientEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
      }
    ],
    "soapNameSpace": "xxxxx",
    "url": "xxxx",
    "useSoapInterface": "true"
  },
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "dishant.arora@caseflowacumen.com",
        "name": "Dishant Arora",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "Sign Here",
              "xPosition": "100",
              "yPosition": "500"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: Is your listener http or https? http support is being sunset https://support.docusign.com/en/releasenote/May-2017-Service-Pack-Notes

Comment: soapNameSpace is http and URL is https

Comment: Are you creating the envelope using rest or soap?

Comment: Please use requestb.in to check that there are no problems on your side. Please try with and without soap to see if that is an issue

Comment: Hi, I'm using restapi call

Comment: Still having a problem?

Comment: Yes we still having problem. I have tested it before and it was working with alright for same request I posted and all of sudden it stopped send webhooks back.

Comment: Please provide an envelope number where it did not work. Also, carefully check that you didn't misspell any of the parameter names.

Comment: I would turn on the option requireAcknowledgment = "true" Then see if there is a failure log. Did you try with http://requestb.in  ?

Comment: Thanks Larry.
Will give it a go and let you know the result and also send you envelope id.

Comment: Thanks Larry. turning on requiredAcknowledge helped me find error. It was one of the dependency dll was missing